# Why code is not giving proper results Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, computer-vision, camera-calibration, projection-matrix

I know this type of questions may have been answered before but i am a beginner in matlab so please bear my kiddy questions.
I wan to generate a 11*12 matrix from a set of values. i have five different vectors named X,Y Z,u,v. 
my code is:
A=zeros(12,11);

```
for i=1:6
A=[X(i) Y(i) Z(i) 1 0 0 0 0 (-u(i)*X(i)) (-u(i)*Y(i)) (-u(i)*Z(i)),0 0 0 0 X(i) Y(i) Z(i) 1 (-v(i)*X(i)) (-v(i)*Y(i)) (-v(i)*Z(i))];
end
```

Here for each iteration i want to fill two rows. So it becomes 12 rows in total. But the problem is that
1. it is giving me 22*1 matrix
2. It is giving wrong values
That means it is appending columns in each iteration that i do not want. 
Kindly help me to find a 11*12 matrix. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the values of `X,Y,Z,u,v` or at least their dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a completely new matrix to `A` on every iteration, so this will result in what you get.

What you want is to replace the rows each iteration. You can index the matrix to do this:

```
A(1,:) = [1 2 3 4];
```

This, for example, will replace the first row with the given values. So you can use

```
A(i*2-1,:)=[X(i) Y(i) Z(i) 1 0 0 0 0 (-u(i)*X(i)) (-u(i)*Y(i)) (-u(i)*Z(i))];
A(i*2,:)=[0 0 0 0 X(i) Y(i) Z(i) 1 (-v(i)*X(i)) (-v(i)*Y(i)) (-v(i)*Z(i))];
```

Unfortunately I don't have Matlab here now to see if you could combine those into one line by indexing `A(i*2-1:i*2,:)` or not.